# how to parse kubelet log with fluentd

Tags: parsing, fluentd, kubelet

The origal kubelet log is such like this:

```
I0605 09:03:41.463195   28799 setters.go:72] Using node IP: "10.127.7.174"
```

I can parse it in fluentd as:

```
format1 /^(?<severity>\w)(?<time>\d{4} [^\s]*)\s+(?<pid>\d+)\s+(?<source>[^ \]]+)\] (?<message>.*)/
```

However, kubespary deploy kubelet as following:
1. journald collects kubelet log;
2. I write a rsyslog file, so kubelet log can be stored in /var/log/kubelet.log.
And the log changes to:

```
Jun  5 09:03:41 k8s-4 kubelet: I0605 09:03:41.463195   28799 setters.go:72] Using node IP: "10.127.7.174"
```

I wonder how to parse this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've tried to parse your log example file and use the following `regexp` filter to achieve the result:

`format /(?<time>[^ ]* {1,2}[^ ]* [^ ]*) (?<host>[^ ]*) (?<ident>[^ :\[]*)(?:\[(?<pid>[0-9]+)\])?(?:[^\:]*\:)? *(?<message>.*)$/`

This will split keys accordingly as per [Fluentular](http://fluentular.herokuapp.com/) output:

> **time**  2019/06/06 08:19:35 +0000
>
> **host**  k8s-4
>
> **ident** kubelet
>
> **message**   I0605 09:03:41.463195 28799 setters.go:72] Using node IP:
>   "10.127.7.174"

In order to get more stuff to learn about Fluentd `regexp` just read [documentation](https://docs.fluentd.org/parser/regexp).

FYI. There is also opportunity to capture logs from `systemd` via [fluent-plugin-systemd](http://ttps://github.com/reevoo/fluent-plugin-systemd/blob/master/docs/matching.md) as well.